# Why is Python not updated on Mac after I used homebrew to install Python 3?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to update Python 2.7 to Python 3.4. Currently, I am using Mac OS X 10.9.5.

I have used Homebrew to install Python 3.4. However, when I used `python -V` to check the version of my Python in the terminal, it still appears to be on the 2.7 version.

[image]

Anybody have any idea as for why this is?

Also, I have tried to follow the directions of this article to update to Python 3 (see the second half of the article). Yet my system cannot find this file: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4`

Comment: Because you've installed `python3`, not *"updated"* `python` (which you shouldn't do - changing the system Python could lead to all kinds of problems). Try `python3 -V`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe According to the answer below, I can make a symlink from python to python3. Would this lead to problems also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install python3 using homebrew.

```
brew install python3
```

Second you may want to use python3 as default change the ~/.bash_aliases to point to python3. This can be done by adding the following command in the **~/.bash_aliases**.

```
alias python='python3'
```

now all the python command gets referred to python3 by default.

*EDIT 1:*
Try running the following command.

```
/usr/bin/env python3
```

This will make python3 as default environment for python executables.

*EDIT 2:*
[Like suggested by robert]
try making a symlink from python to python3. this makes python3 as default environment in all shells.

Comment: This will only work when `python` is invoked from bash. I suggest actually running `python3` or making a symlink from `python` to `python3` in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Try running the following command. `/usr/bin/env python3` . This will make python3 as default python executable environment

Comment: Yeah @robert that will be a better solution. I will update my answer.